# C library for JSON files in Windows

Tags: c, json, windows

do you know libraries in C that manage JSON files (mainly read and write) on Windows System?

I can not find any suitable library easy to use under windows, but I am not an expert!

Thanks for any support you can provide to me.

PR

Comment: Hard to know what the problem is. There are countless JSON libraries written in C.

Comment: I have used mjson (http://mjson.sourceforge.net/) successfully in flvmeta for Windows.

Comment: This really lacks minimal effort to solve the "problem". Really nothing from the suggested by http://json.org didn't do the trick ?

Answer (score 3):

[JSON homepage](http://www.json.org/) lists all the libraries for different kind of languages. This is the what is listed for C:

- [JSON_checker](http://www.json.org/JSON_checker/)
- [YAJL](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/)
- [js0n](http://github.com/quartzjer/js0n/blob/master/js0n.c)
- [LibU](http://github.com/koanlogic/libu/blob/master/srcs/toolbox/json.c)
- [json-c](https://github.com/jehiah/json-c)
- [json-parser](https://github.com/udp/json-parser)
- [jsonsl](https://github.com/mnunberg/jsonsl)
- [WJElement](https://github.com/netmail-open/wjelement)
- [M's JSON parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjson/)
- [cJSON](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjson/)
- [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/)
- [jsmn](https://bitbucket.org/zserge/jsmn/wiki/Home)
- [cson](http://fossil.wanderinghorse.net/wikis/cson/?page=cson)
- [parson](http://kgabis.github.com/parson/)
- [ujson4c](https://github.com/esnme/ujson4c/)
- [nxjson](https://bitbucket.org/yarosla/nxjson/src)
- [frozen](https://github.com/cesanta/frozen)

Answer (score 1):

Well I can find at least this variants ...

- jansson http://www.digip.org/jansson/
- json-c https://github.com/json-c/json-c